# Download image issue in C#. Downloads html instead

Tags: c#, image, http, httpwebrequest, webclient

There are images (captchas) i need to download. [This](http://www.networksolutions.com/enhancedWHOISImageKey.do;jsessionid=a13de18b7fcd524901515396c71e%3aatyy?method-show=&2.0911881306666568E7=&org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=065afed36df4b0e5bc49c02a025291c8) is an example.

If you open that link in any browser it shows an image, but when i'm trying to download that image in code it gives me an html page, which contains only link to main page - http://www.networksolutions.com/. What am i doing wrong? Here are two code examples:

```
byte[] data = new WebClient().DownloadData(imgURL);

AND

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgURL);
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
req.KeepAlive = true;

byte[] data;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        int contentLength = (int)response.ContentLength;
        data = new byte[contentLength];

        for (int pos = 0; pos < contentLength; ++pos)
        {
            int len = s.Read(data, pos, contentLength - pos);                                            
            pos += len;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `imgURL`?  The link you provided appears to be to a page that will produce the image.  Not the image itself.

Comment: No, that url is actual image url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because the server detects that the request is not made by a web browser. If you specify a user agent header, it correctly downloads the image:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(imgURL)
```

Comment: You're right! How could i forget about setting user agent? My fault.